# Which sentence is correct? Passive or past?

Tags: sentence-choice

1. Car were drowned by water (actually in the water).
2. Car drowned in water.

Sentence 1 is passive, if I use 'by' then water acting as an agent but where the car drowned? 'In the water' is not mentioned.

Should I say in passive like "Car is drowned by water in  water".

Comment: Cars cannot drown. Only living creatures can drown (die) by being **submerged** in water. Also your sentence lacks articles, and you seem unsure about singular and plural. The cars were submerged in (or covered by) water. The car was submerged in water.

Comment: Okay I got you.

Comment: Are you asking about passive versus active voice of drowned? Could be a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139256/use-of-the-passive-voice-with-the-verb-drown ?

Comment: The car has been submerged by the water (but actually it has to be in the water) should I say 'the car has been submerged by the water in the water'?

Comment: You really need to change your example. Not only can cars not drown (as already said), but water cannot really be the active cause of drowning. While one person can drown another (the verb can also be intransitive, where one person simply *does* drown), *water* can't be an active agent of the drowning. People drown *in* water (or some other liquid), but they are never drowned *by* water. To say *the water drowned me* is understandable, but also somewhat nonsensical. That would just be taken as *I drowned in water* or simply *I drowned*.

Comment: Then how to make the passive ? Please let me know

Comment: How to make *which* passive? You can make the active *I drowned him* passive with *he was drowned by me.*

Comment: @Jason Bassford The car has been submerged in water by the water. Am I right? –

Comment: No. Again, *water* isn't an active agent when it comes to that verb. You can't say *water submerged the car*.

Comment: Please then give passive.